# "AssertionError: Only python 2.7 and later is supported by ptyprocess", when installing pexpect via pip on python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pexpect

I got following error when trying install pexpect via pip:

```
# pip install pexpect
Collecting pexpect
do_ypcall: clnt_call: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached pexpect-4.0.tar.gz
Collecting ptyprocess>=0.5 (from pexpect)
  Using cached ptyprocess-0.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-2X4It7/ptyprocess/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        "Only python 2.7 and later is supported by ptyprocess.")
    AssertionError: Only python 2.7 and later is supported by ptyprocess.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2X4It7/ptyprocess
```

It's pretty clear that downloaded `ptyprocess` works only with python 2.7, but doesn't `pip` should download correct packages versions, that are compatible with installed `python` versions?

My system info:

`pip -V: pip 7.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages  (python 2.6)`

`python -V: Python 2.6.6`

`OS: CentOS 6.3`

BTW: `yum install pexpect` succesfully installs pexpect package

Thank You

Comment: Hmm, are you certain the `requirements.txt` (if there is one) doesn't contain incorrect library versions?  You may have simply uncovered a bug in their setup for that package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AssertionError: Only python 2.7 and later is supported by ptyprocess.`

`pyexpect` depends on `ptyprocess>=0.5` (https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/setup.py#L66)

You will need to install a version of `ptyprocess` that is >=0.5 but works with python 2.6 first, then install `pyexpect`.

**edit** looks like you are out of luck, 0.5 requires python 2.7 (https://github.com/pexpect/ptyprocess/blob/master/setup.py#L9-L10). Your system package has it patched to work with 2.6 so you'll have to use that.

Comment: Or upgrade to python 2.7, but that's another story :) ...Thanks!

Comment: But shouldn't `pip` initially download packages for 2.6 only?

Comment: @Samuel I don't know how that mechanism works but `ptyprocess`'s `setup.py` has an `assert` in it that runs before the call to `setup()` so that may be why it fails that way.

Answer (score 4):

yum will install pexpect v2.3.6.

easy_install or pip will install pexpect v4.0.1 as of today.

You can use pexpect version 3.3 which not depends on ptyprocess version.

```
# easy_install pexpect==3.3
```

or

```
# pip install pexpect==3.3
```